# Oracle Historgram and reading wrong index

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I have 2 databases, one is the main database that many users work on it and a testing database, the second one is test database that loaded by a `dump` from the main DB.

I have a select query a with join conditions and union all on a table `TAB11` that contains 40 million rows.

The problem that the query is reading wrong index in the `main DB` but in `test DB` is reading correct index. Note that both have latest gather statistics on the table and same count rows. I start to dig into histograms and skew data and I noticed in main DB the table has 37 histogram created on its columns ,however in the test db the table has only 14 columns has histogram. so apparently those created histogram are effecting the query plan to read wrong index (right?). ( those histogram created by oracle , and not by anyone)

My question:

-should I remove the histogram from those columns, and when I gather static again oracle will create the needed one and read them correctly ? but I am afraid it will effect the performance of the table.

-should I add this when i gather tab statistics       `method_opt=>'for all columns size skewonly'` but I am not sure if the data are skewed or not.

-should I run gather index stats on the desired index and the oracle might read it?

how to make the query read the right index, without droping it or using force index?

Comment: Did you gather statistics manually or was it done by automatic job?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i guess its a job ( automatic) , are there difference if its manually or automatic ?

Comment: Yes, try `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS;` - it is more "aggressive" than the automatic one.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its a big database with lot of rows , it will affect the tables and the performance right ? useally they are using this as automatic `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname => 'SH',tabname => 'TAB1', degree => 4)` if ran it manually it will make difference right ?

Comment: Gathering only single tables is also fine

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did one manually but still reading wrong index, is itpossible something wrong in histogram ?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many possible reasons for choosing a different index in one DB vs another (including object life-cycle differences e.g. when data gets loaded, deletions/truncations/inserts/stats gathering index rebuilds ...).  Having said that, in cases like this I usually do a parameter by parameter comparison of the initialization parameters on each DB; also an object by object comparison (you've already observed a delta in the histogram; thee may be others as well that are impacting this).

Comment: Thanks your answer, well the parameters are the same ( its a fresh dump ). as for the object life cycle I start to compare histograms , what kind of impact could be happens ? I checked this table `user_tab_modifications` and `tab1` has the same counts.  So i conclude the problem in histogram.

Comment: Dont you think the histogram with such difference between the 2 database  can cause wrong reading wrong index? if yes how i can i solve it ?

Comment: Fresh dump doesn't necessarily mean that the parameters are the same.  I agree that histograms are not likely the issue.  Object life-cycle example: I have seen cases where app makes index unusable; loads data; <something unusual happens here>; and index does not get re-built.   Subsequent queries don't use the index.  There are other object life-cycle scenarios that can cause this.  If you want, you can try to flush the SQL from the shared pool (just this one [Google it]) and see if the optimizer is picking up the wrong index because of past object life-cycle condition that is no longer there